# Restrict access to Google Cloud Storage hosted website

Tags: google-cloud-storage, access-control

We have a production website running on a host e.g. **domain.com**
We gonna use haproxy to proxy requests from **domain.com** to **static.domain.com** - which is a domain-named bucket in Cloud Storage. Also we have a development version which is also served on Cloud Storage at **static.dev.domain.com**.

So it turns out that the same page will be available on 3 different domains, which is very bad from the SEO perspective.

My initial idea was to restrict access to domain-named buckets by IP but I see no way to do it. No way for basic http authorization either. Any ideas how to protect static web sites from being indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not possible to restrict the access to one IP from the Cloud Storage console, nevertheless, I found this [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/63068776) that requests the restriction of a bucket access by an IP Address. As a recommendation, I suggest you to do a comment and start the issue so you can get notifications about this.

On the other hand, I think that this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291342/google-storage-access-based-on-ip-address) could helps you since this one mentions a possible workaround using VPC Service Controls :)

Answer (score 0):

Since my main concern was SEO, to solve duplicate content issue I added canonical url:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">
```